# How do I remove a SwingX AutoCompleteDecorator?

Tags: java, jtable, swingx

I am using a SwingX AutoCompleteDecorator on the JTextField of a DefaultCellEditor. However, I'm using the same Editor on multiple columns of the table. The auto-complete suggestions will have to differ between columns, as would the strict/non-strict adherence.

Code up to now is:

```
class MyEditor extends DefaultCellEditor {

public MyEditor() {
  super(new JTextField());
}

public Component getTableCellEditorComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, int row, int column) {
  JTextField field = (JTextField) super.getTableCellEditorComponent(table, value, isSelected, row, column);

  List<String> suggestions = this.getSuggestions(column, value);

  if (column == 2) {
    AutoCompleteDecorator.decorate(field, suggestions, true);
  }

  if (column == 3) {
    AutoCompleteDecorator.decorate(field, suggestions, false);
  }

  return field;
}
```

What seems to happen is that the first time the Editor is called, everything works fine. On subsequent calls (or rather, calls on any other column than the first call), the decorator for, say, column 3 is added on top of the decorator for column 2, which doesn't do much good.

SwingX documentation is rather sparse on that topic. I have found out that the Decorator seems to add a `FocusListener` to the textfield.

Does anyone know how to either reset the decorator or at least find out which FocusListener (there are three on the field after the decorator has been called) should be removed?

Thanks!

Comment: hmm ... you might have hit a bug: the decorate method internally calls undecorate, so the intention clearly is to cleanup any old decoration. If that doesn't happen, something is wrong. Please consider to file a bug in the SwingX project's issue tracker. As a (crude ;-) workaround, I would suggest to use different editors, set per-column

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I've been doing now. Even so, wouldn't it be good to have the undecorate method accessible along with decorate? I can think of a number of scenarios in which I would want a textfield to lose the decorator without setting a new one. I suppose decorate(field, new ArrayList<String>(), false) would do the trick, but it seems counterintuitive to me. Will file a bug report.

Comment: would have thought the undecorate being public as well :-) Thanks for filing the issue!